# Mysql Multiple AND queries on same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in format [image]

I want to create query like this

```
Select entry_id from table where form_id='6' AND (field='0' AND value
= 'John2') AND (field_id='2' AND value >'5')  AND .......so on
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: hi, there's no "field" in your database. maybe "field_id" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT entry_id 
FROM table 
WHERE form_id='6' 
  AND (field_id, value) IN ( (0, 'John2'), 
                             (2, 'ssa'),
                             .......so on
                           )
GROUP BY entry_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field_id, value) = {the amount of distinct value pairs}
```

Comment: Note that MySQL doesn't optimise this type of thing particularly well (unless something's changed recently)

Comment: @Strawberry Index `(entry_id, form_id, field_id, value)` or `(form_id, field_id, value, entry_id)` may be used (both are covering, must be tested what is more suitable - this depends on table statistic).

Comment: If that's true then it's new .

Comment: thanks! Is there any way to use other operators in where condition like field_id='2' AND value > 5 ?

Comment: @aman *Is there any way to use other operators in where condition like field_id='2' AND value > 5 ?* No, shown conditions structure does not allow this. No way to distinguish does the parameters pair needs in equiality check or in some non-equiality one.

Comment: @aman PS. When you want to edit the base of the question (not to clarify it) you must create new question.